# Tech Support-Provider for Craft CMS

Tags: services

we are a small team in Berlin, Germany, developing editorial websites based on craft cms. A major publishing house is interested in our services. A condition to get contracted is us to provide a certain (t.b.d.) level of tech support – a requirement that we can´t match since we are just a small company. Now my question: does anybody know a tech support-provider in germany to whom we could "outsource" this service?

Answer (score 8):

This is Leslie, I'm the Chief Customer Officer for Craft CMS. I'm not sure I can help, but I'd like to know more. Specifically I'm not sure I can source a dev shop in Germany, but I may be able to get close. We do have Service Partners and we are privately testing a couple of service plans both directly from us and from contracting 3rd party shops that specialize in this type of support. Knowing more details will help us figure out how to develop this type of support from the community and directly from us. Please email me directly at Leslie@Craftcms.com.